# How do I mount a linux_raid_member filesystem with my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, raid, mount, mdadm

We have a server that just died after ten years of service.

It has four hard drives. Two are in one Raid 1 array and two are in another.

I have managed to merge the firs two back into being one array with mdadm with this command

sudo mdadm --create --level=1 /dev/md0 --metadata=0.90 --raid-device=2 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc

The partition that I need to access is now under the filesystem 'linux_raid_member'. Is there a way I can mount this to see and read the files in this hard drive to get them off?

Comment: `linux_raid_member` is not a filesystem. What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Whenever I load the raid in Ubuntu Disks Utility it comes up saying the file system is linux_raid_member. I'm not sure if I am reading correctly, or if the partition manager is getting confused, but I can't find any information on what exactly this is.